Laptop connected with HP USB-C Dock G5 cannot shut down properly
I use an HP USB-C Dock G5(S/N: 5CG321Z29T) with my Dell Latitude 5531 laptop. Specifications below,

OS: Windows 10 Pro
OS Version: 22H2
RAM: 32GB

I connected the dock to the USB-C port of the laptop. The port can be used to charge the laptop too. I connected two monitors via DP port. I connected my keyboard, mouse and other peripherals to USB ports in the dock.
If I tried to shut down my PC, the grey background with the shutdown circle of Windows 10 is running endlessly. I checked the user manual and it describes if such a situation happened, we need to press the dock button 5 seconds to shut down the computer. I tried that too. But after a few minutes, it becomes a blue screen error.
Otherwise, I need to remove the dock connection before getting the blue screen to shut down normally. Could you please provide technical support. If you are not clear with my description, please feel free to ask your doubts.

Update: I updated the dock firmware, LAN driver, and audio driver. But nothing helps. While showing infinite loading I just removed the LAN cable from the docking station and the laptop shut down correctly. Then I tried multiple times without connecting the LAN cable to the docking station and it is correctly shutting down normally. So, till I get a solution I need to connect the LAN cable directly to the laptop instead of the docking station.

If you are sure all processes have completed, and no data is being written, you can force complete shutdown:

Press WindowsR.
Copy the following into the edit box: shutdown /s /f /t 00.
Press Enter and the PC should shut down immediately.

That same command can be saved as a batch file by copying and pasting into Notepad, and saving with the extension .bat, e.g., force_shutdown.bat. Make a keyboard shortcut to that to force immediate shutdown with a key combination. N.B. Pick a combo one is not likely to hit accidentally.

The workaround is good. I like it. But I need to resolve the root cause

Consider how you try to shut down -- sleep, hibernate, fast-boot shutdown, or true shutdown, which is what shutdown /s /t 00 does (notice, /f removed; this is not forcing immediate shutdown). Do all have that issue?

I am doing true shutdown every time
